# jQuery smooth scrolling on whole body instead of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This website has a `div` with smooth scrolling:

http://fatlinesofcode.github.io/jquery.smoothwheel/demo/smoothwheel.html

But how can I make this smooth scrolling on the whole `body` instead of a `div`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And it will smooth scroll the whole page, instead of particular `div`. The main crux of this is:

```
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: ...
}, 1000);
```

For more information, have a look at the article: [Smooth Scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I want the smooth scrolling to be on the whole page at all times and not when an anchor link is being clicked.

Comment: @JasonDeClau Still what you said above is unclear. On all the times means?

Comment: Sorry English isn't my native language, I find it hard to explain. This wordpress theme has the effect I want (https://wp-themes.com/zerif-lite/). Scroll and it's very smooth. I also want that effect.

Comment: @JasonDeClau Ha. That's better.

Comment: @JasonDeClau Just add this script to your page buddy. [**Script**](https://wp-themes.com/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/js/smoothscroll.js?ver=20120206). This is what they have used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on using the jQuery extension that you referenced: Looking through the source code you can just call the smoothWheel function on the document instead of the div.

(https://fatlinesofcode.github.io/jquery.smoothwheel/src/jquery.smoothwheel.js)

**Initialize:**

```
$(document).smoothWheel()
```

**Disable function:**

```
$(document).smoothWheel({'remove':true})
```

**DEMO:**

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/0omtkbvt/